# Google 'Check your passwords" error every time I login in on my website

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome, flask

So I am making a somewhat social media website that uses, flask on the backend and HTML, javascript, and w3-CSS on the front end.
I am taking a password and user name from a form and sending it to a route.
Also, I am saving the user id, as Session cookies on the server for autologin purposes.
Every time I log in, someone logs in from their created account, this message pops up.
[The error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzmBu.jpg)

Can someone suggest any fixes?

Here is the backend and front end code for reference:

backend:

```
@app.route('/handle_login', methods=['POST','GET'])
def handle_login():
    print("HANDLE LOGIN")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['pass']
        #password is then checked with username and password in SQL database
```

frontend:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('handle_login') }}" autocomplete="off" method="post" >  
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"  required="true" placeholder="Username" >
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="pass"  required="true" placeholder="Enter Password" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="login_submit"  value="Login" >
</form>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your site or your code. It's telling you that one of the passwords that you've stored in the Google password manager has been found on the Dark Web and your security is potentially compromised. You should check what passwords/sites you've stored in Google and then change those passwords.

Comment: Okay, for demo purpose, i have used 'aniket' as username and same as password. It's not just with me, other people who are testing the site are having the same error msg popping up. Also, if i remove type="password", the msg does not pop up. But then password is clearly visible.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the reason my website was giving me this error. So it's still in development phase and I had been creating accounts just like that for testing. Apparently, this error is thrown with the accounts that have username and password same. By changing the password slightly does not give any error.
So for me, that was the fix.